# Float object is not iterable [Python]

Tags: python

Hey i'm new to python programming, and i encountered a problem in my function, while i have no floats in it.
It's basically a Value iteration algo to solve a snake & Ladders game, and i have this error: float object is not iterable, in my Q function of my algo.
I know this error is trivial, so i hope you can easily help me.
Thanks a lot.

```
class Snakes_Ladders(object):


    def __init__(self, N):
        self.N=N

    def Begin(self):
        return 1


    def isEnd(self, state):

        return state == self.N

    def discount(self):
        return 1.

    def states(self):
        return range(1, self.N+1)

    def actions(self, state):
        result=[]
        if state<=self.N or state+1<=self.N:
            result.append('Security')
        if state<=self.N or state+1<=self.N or state+2<=self.N:
            result.append('Normal')
        return result

    def TransiMat(self, state, action):
        result = []
    #Returns a list with (NewState,Proba, Reward)
        if action=='Security'and state!=3:
            result.append((state, 0.5, -1))
            result.append((state+1, 0.5, -1))
        if action=='Security' and state==3:
            result.append((state, 0.5, -1))
            result.append((state+1, 0.25, -1))
            result.append((state+8, 0.25, -1))
        if action=='Normal' and state!=3:
            result.append((state, 0.33, -1))
            result.append((state+1, 0.33, -1))
            result.append((state+2, 0.33, -1))
        #fast lane
        if action=='Normal' and state==3:
            result.append((state,0.33,-1))
            result.append((state+1,0.165,-1))
            result.append((state+8,0.165,-1))
          ##Traps
        if action=='Normal' and state==5:
            result.append((0, 0.33, -1))
            result.append((state+1, 0.33, -1))
            result.append((state+2, 0.33, -1))
        if action=='Normal' and state==7:
            result.append((state-3, 0.33, -1))
            result.append((state+1, 0.33, -1))
            result.append((state+2, 0.33, -1))
        if action=='Normal' and state==9:
            result.append((state, 0.33, -1))
            result.append((state+1, 0.33, -1))
            result.append((state+2, 0.33, -1))
        return result


def ValueIteration(game):

    V={} #Initialization
    for state in game.states():
        V[state] = 0.

    def Q(state,action):
        i = 0.
        for result in game.TransiMat(state, action):
                newState=result[0]
                prob=result[1]
                reward=result[2]
                print(type(newState))
        **return sum(prob*(reward + game.discount()*V[newState]))** #The error is called here : Float 
                                                                      object is not iterable

    while True:
        #Compute new values given the old values

        newV = {}
        for state in game.states():
            if game.isEnd(state):
                newV[state]=0.
            else:
                newV[state] = max(Q(state,action) for action in game.actions(state))
  #Convergence
        if max(abs(V[state]- newV[state]) for state in game.states())<1e-10:
            break
        V=newV

  #Policy

    pi={}
    for state in game.states():
        if game.isEnd[state]:
            pi[state]= 'none'
        else:
            pi[state] = max((Q(state,action), action) for action in game.actions(state))[1]

game=Snakes_Ladders(N=15)
#print(game.actions(3))
print(game.TransiMat(1,'Security'))

ValueIteration(game)
```

and there you have the traceback :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-188-35da2c569c07> in <module>
    104 print(game.TransiMat(1,'Security'))
    105 
--> 106 ValueIteration(game)
    107 raise KeyError(message)
    108 

<ipython-input-188-35da2c569c07> in ValueIteration(game)
     85                 newV[state]=0.
     86             else:
---> 87                 newV[state] = max(Q(state,action) for action in game.actions(state))
     88   #Convergence
     89         if max(abs(V[state]- newV[state]) for state in game.states())<1e-10:

<ipython-input-188-35da2c569c07> in <genexpr>(.0)
     85                 newV[state]=0.
     86             else:
---> 87                 newV[state] = max(Q(state,action) for action in game.actions(state))
     88   #Convergence
     89         if max(abs(V[state]- newV[state]) for state in game.states())<1e-10:

<ipython-input-188-35da2c569c07> in Q(state, action)
     75                 reward=result[2]
     76                 print(type(newState))
---> 77         return sum(prob*(reward + game.discount()*V[newState]))
     78 
     79     while True:

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What are you trying to sum there?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: `sum` expects a sequence but your are passing a single number.

Comment: `discount` explicitly returns a float (`1.`) so "I have no floats" is not true. But what's that `sum` supposed to sum up anyway?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)(iterable, /, start=0)
>
> Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total. The iterable’s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string.

Adding a default list inside `sum` should do the trick -

```
def Q(state,action):
    i = 0.
    for result in game.TransiMat(state, action):
        newState=result[0]
        prob=result[1]
        reward=result[2]
        print(type(newState))
    return sum([prob*(reward + game.discount()*V[newState])])
```

Or if only single value is expected then no point using `sum`, just return the value

```
def Q(state,action):
    ...
    return  prob*(reward + game.discount()*V[newState])
```

Comment: My list only contains integers, so it should not be a probleme while calling sum.

Comment: However it does call a type error on V[newState] saying that a float can't be iterated

Comment: `sum` function expects an iterable as input, you provided float

Comment: that's good to know i'll make the necessary switches and see if it does the trick thank you

Comment: This is useless. `sum([...])` with one element in the list is a no-op, you might as well just return that one element if it's what you want. Assuming the OP does really need a sum of something, this doesn't do it, and the question needs more details before it can be answered.

Comment: There isn't just one element, it's an algorith that's gonna loop trhough all different scenarios of the transition matrix, to compute a Q-value, that will then be used to figure out the optimal policy (by maximizing Q)

Comment: @kaya3, I just gave a quickfix to author, but you are right. I added alternative approach as well

Comment: But it's not a "fix" if it doesn't solve the actual problem. The goal is not simply to make the error message go away, otherwise the quickest fix is to delete all of the code.